# Countability of boundary points

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V=\cup_n I_n$ be a countable union of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Is the set of boundary points of $V$ countable? What if the intervals are strictly open (does this even make a difference)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable union of (strictly) open intervals (you can make them disjoint if you want). The complement of the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) has the Cantor set as boundary, which is uncountable.

Comment: And more generally, any perfect set is uncountable and is the boundary of an open set (its complement).

Comment: @Robert: You mean nowhere dense. I am fairly certain that $[0,1]$ is perfect and is not the boundary of its complement. :-)

Comment: What is a strictly open interval?

Comment: @Matt: strictly open as opposed to one-sided open, I assume. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: Oh I see. It's vocabulary from the question.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I  meant nowhere dense perfect set.

Comment: On this matter of points in the Cantor set that are not endpoints of any of the complements of deleted middle thirds, not that some of them are rational numbers: in particular $1/4$ and $3/10$ are members of the Cantor set.